# Kile shortcut stops working

Tags: pdftex, windows, kile

I have been using `Kile` for quite some time now and I have never experienced this problem. But I had to format my computer and I reinstalled Kile and a problem with `{` occurred. So the shortcut for this is `Alt Gr + B` which is working fine until I first convert TeX to PDF using PDFLatex and then view the PDF. After that, the shortcut `Alt Gr + B` stops working and I can't insert `{` anymore. Its like the PDF viewer interferes with the shortcut? I don't know. It's weird.

Anyone else has the same problem?

I installed the KILE from their official website: [here](https://kile.sourceforge.io/).

here are pictures of steps that trigger the bug.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBfeD.jpg

Or easier question: where can I report this bug to developers?

Comment: I am not sure I follow: are you using `Alt-Gr+B` to insert an opening brace? Isn't that a character regularly found on your keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it working fine until I compile a .tex file with PDFLatex(option in KILE) and I view the document on the sidebar. Maybe with pictures....hm...? Let me know if there are still some uncertanties.

Comment: I posted pictures of steps.

Comment: Which Kile version are you using? If you're still on 2.1.3 consider switching to version 3. Even if it's labeled as "beta" is very stable and is what most people use today.

Comment: @OldNick Im on KIle 3 And this occurs if I get it from Microsfot Store or if I download it. Same problem.